# Find the rate of convergence of given sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

> Find the rate of convergence of given sequence.
> $$x_{n+1}=\frac{-9}{x_n-6}$$

Here the what I tried and definition of rate of convergence.

- A sequence is said to be convergent with order $k(> 1)$ if $\exists \space c > 0 $and $N > 0$ such that,
  $\varepsilon_{n+1} ≤ c\varepsilon^k_n$
  $\forall n>N$ where $c$ is the rate of convergence.

Therefore by using definition I tried $$|x_{n+1}-3|=\frac{3|x_{n}-3|}{|x_{n}-6|}=|x_{n}-3|\bigg(\dfrac{3}{|x_{n}-6|} \bigg)$$

I have no idea to handle part $\bigg(\dfrac{3}{|x_{n}-6|} \bigg)$

Can anyone help me to find the rate of convergence?

Comment: You've found the fixed point.  Write $x_n=3+y_n$ and write the original formula as a series in $y_n$

Comment: @Empy2 Ok then?

Comment: Which side of 3 is it convergent?

Comment: @Empy2 $y_{n} \to 0 $  as $ n \to \infty$?

Comment: Try some initial values for $x_1$ and calculate $x2,x3,x4,x5$ for each

Comment: @Empy2 I tried it  but I have no idea to handle

Comment: I've run out of ideas.  Good luck.

Comment: Have you proved that it converges at all?

Comment: @Momo I think it converges to $3$

Comment: @PierreCarre I am using a different definition therefore I don't know much about others, that is why I tried to get the answer using my definition

Comment: @ALMEra Your definition is equivalent to the others.

Comment: you have $\frac{3}{|x_n-6|}\approx 1$ for $n$ large enough, so you have $k=1$ (sublinear convergence). Your definition requires $k>1$. This being said, it is easy to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_{k+2}-x_{k+1}|}{|x_{k+1}-x_k|}=1$ to prove logarithmic convergence.

Comment: @Momo How did  you get that?

Comment: $x_n\to 3$ so $\frac{3}{|x_n-6|}\to 1$ so $\frac{3}{|x_n-6|}<1+\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you set $g(x)=\frac{-9}{x-6}$, then $g'(3)=1$. This means that there is no direct claim on stability possible, no linear convergence. One would need less usual methods to explore the convergence.

One can linearize the computation by setting $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$. This has one degree of freedom, which can be used to separate the recursion equation
$$
\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{-9q_n}{p_n-6q_n}=\frac{9q_n}{6q_n-p_n}
$$
into the linear system
$$
\pmatrix{p_{n+1}\\q_{n+1}}
=
\pmatrix{0&9\\-1&6}
\pmatrix{p_n\\q_n}
$$
This can be solved via eigen-decomposition, or by reducing to a second order recursion equation
$$
q_{n+2}-6q_{n+1}=-p_{n+1}=-9q_n
$$

From the explicit solution formula that results one can directly read off the convergence.